# Apis for accessing video data from Break.com using Android / Java apps

Tags: java, android, video

I am developing an app in android, where I want to get videos from Break.com
http://www.break.com/

Is there any API exposed(sdk) from Break for android developers to access the contents or is there any way to do REST communication to get the data, like youtube data apis.

Is it possible to get the content Id of the video from Break, below is the url:
http://www.break.com/index/8-month-old-hears-mom-for-the-first-time-2175717
Is 2175717 the content id for the url.
Any idea in this regard will be useful.

Thanks in advance.
Pallavi.

Comment: Is it possible to get the content Id of the video from Break, below is the url: http://www.break.com/index/8-month-old-hears-mom-for-the-first-time-2175717 Is 2175717 the content id for the url. Any idea in this regard will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Break.com does not offer a public API.

Comment: Yes,So is it not possible to access the contents from Break?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

Comment: ok thanks, I shall try other alternatives to access Break mobile web page.

Comment: You could try crawling the site, but I'm not sure if that's allowed in their terms of use. Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted.